# Qual o comando compatível no SQL Server ao SHOW CREATE TABLE do MySQL?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, tsql

Qual seria o comando no SQL Server para visualizar o *script* de criação de uma determinada tabela?

Com resultado mais ou menos assim:

```
+------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| table_name |                 create_statement                  |
+------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| customers  | CREATE TABLE customers (                          |
|            |                                                   |
|            |     id INT NOT NULL,                              |
|            |                                                   |
|            |     email STRING NULL,                            |
|            |                                                   |
|            |     CONSTRAINT "primary" PRIMARY KEY (id ASC),    |
|            |                                                   |
|            |     UNIQUE INDEX customers_email_key (email ASC), |
|            |                                                   |
|            |     FAMILY "primary" (id, email)                  |
|            |                                                   |
|            | )                                                 |
+------------+---------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: a opção mais simples é ir no menu "Script", mas esse resultado ai não existe em nenhuma tabela, vai ter de combinar os resultados pra gerar isso

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 1):

**Não tem como**, você pode obter a informação que deseja de outras formas, por exemplo

```
sp_help customers
```

Ou

```
exec sp_columns customers
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Procedure/Execute.sql).

Ou pode obter algo parecido na GUI indo em `Script Table As` ->`Create`.

[Conforme SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3526982/221800).

Comment: obrigado por seu retorno. Esses comandos eu já conhecia. O mais aproximado do que preciso está em quando faço um select na sys.all_sql_modules, no entanto a coluna definition mostra o script de criação das views e procedures. Eu estava precisando mesmo do script de criação de uma determinada tabela.